# Solve $(a-b)^2$ with $(r_1a-r_2b)^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, problem-solving

Is it possible to solve for 
$$(a-b)^2$$

by knowing only the following information:
$$(r_1a-r_2b)^2 = C$$
$$r_1$$
$$r_2$$
$$C$$

Comment: No, for example if we have $(3a + 2b)^2 = 144$, we can have $a=2, b=3$ or $a=0, b=6$

Comment: @TCiur If we want the $r_i$ to be positive, we can make $(3\cdot 8-2\cdot6)^2=(3\cdot6-2\cdot3)^2=144$, but $(8-6)^2\neq (6-3)^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=a-b$. So we are trying to find $x^2$.

We know that $(r_1a-r_2b)^2=C$. Next substitute in for $x$:

$$(r_1(x+b)-r_2b)^2=C$$

$$r_1(x+b)-r_2b=\pm\sqrt{C}$$

$$x+b-\frac{r_2b}{r_1}=\pm\frac{\sqrt{C}}{r_1}$$

$$x=-b+\frac{r_2b}{r_1}\pm\frac{\sqrt{C}}{r_1}$$

$$x^2=\left(-b+\frac{r_2b}{r_1}\pm\frac{\sqrt{C}}{r_1}\right)^2$$

Note that $x^2$ depends upon the value of $b$ which we do not know so it can not be found from the information given.